# JavaScript async function returns object Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, request-promise

I'm trying to figure out, how to return from JavaScript  `async` function.

In `Node.js`  application `script.js` I have a function:

```
  let result = getresult(input);
```

must be `async function` with `/content` tag in `await fetch` to insert, send `msg: input` value to  `server.js` functions, and return `result` value.  In `script.js`:

```
async function getresult(input) {
  const request = await fetch(
    `/content?${new URLSearchParams({
      msg: input,
    })}`
  );
  const serverRes = await request.json();
  console.log("Server response: ", serverRes );
  return serverRes ;
}
```

Chrome console successfully shows requested string `Server response: {text: 'hello!'}`, but `return` returns `[object Promise]`

I'm not sure, what I'm doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let result = await getresult(input);
```

You must await the result of your asynchronous function.